# Download file from browser using selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I know this question has been asked a couple of times but the solutions for the posted questions are not helping my case.

I want to download a dataset from this website:
https://datadashboard.fda.gov/ora/cd/inspections.htm

I have to click on the "dataset" and then click on "entire inspection dataset" in the dropdown to download the dataset I require.
[image]

Here is the HTML for "dataset":

[image]

Here is the HMTL for "entire inspection dataset":

[image]

here is my code to get the dataset:

```
iconDownload = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="expand-d"]').click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "expand-d")))

downloadDataset = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="exp-dt1"]')
downloadDataset.click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 120, 1).until(checkDownload)
```

I have also tried:

```
    iconDownload = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span[class=\'icon-download\']").click()
```

but I am getting this error:

File "FDAComplianceDashboardInspections-GetFileHash.py", line 68, in saveSearchResults
iconDownload = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="expand-d"]').click()
File "/home/devuser/code/data-sourcing/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 80, in click
self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
File "/home/devuser/code/data-sourcing/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
return self._parent.execute(command, params)
File "/home/devuser/code/data-sourcing/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/home/devuser/code/data-sourcing/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (400, 759)
(Session info: headless chrome=65.0.3325.181)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.544315 (730aa6a5fdba159ac9f4c1e8cbc59bf1b5ce12b7),platform=Linux 5.10.25-linuxkit x86_64)

Note: I have tried find_element_by_id, find_element_by_class, find_element_by_css_selector but nothing is working.

It's my first time working with selenium and would really appreciate the help to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check with this, Hope it will work for you

```
driver.get("https://datadashboard.fda.gov/ora/cd/inspections.htm")
driver.maximize_window()

driver.find_element_by_id("expand-d").click()
driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,400)");
time.sleep(15)
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Entire Inspections Dataset").click()
```